# How to initialize Spring bean at very beginning of Spring initialization?

Tags: java, spring, initialization

I would like to use in my Spring Boot application [flywaydb](https://flywaydb.org/) to update / initialize database from `SQL` alter files on initialization. Java code, that process Flywaydb, should be executed after Spring `datasource` is created (Flywaydb needs `javax.sql.DataSource`) BUT before application beans are initialized. I am aware of `@DependsOn` annotation bud I don't want to avoid to set this on all application beans.

Is there some way how to initialize specific bean in specified order?

Comment: Don't... Flyway is supported out-of-the-box with Spring Boot you don't need to do anything special for it. You are basically making it more complex by trying to work around the framework. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't do anything special. Spring Boot has [support for Flyway out-of-the-box](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup). There are only 3 steps to take

1. Add [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) as a dependency
2. Put your migration scripts in `src/main/resources/db/migration`
3. Start your application

You don't need to add annotations, create beans or use callbacks. The Spring Team already thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a bean callback to happen exactly once when the application is ready to start, all beans are ready and will not get called again when the context is refreshed then a good Spring Boot recipe is to use the `ApplicationReadyEvent` like this:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
  // do tasks that should happen once on startup
}
```

Comment: No, I need to call my code **before** all other beans are ready - because the depend on actual DB structure that I need to actualize before.

Comment: OK then perhaps you need a [context initializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context)? I've used the `ApplicationStartedEvent` myself to retrieve key data that the rest of the context depended upon.